# Установка найденного списка приложений в Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Команда `apt-cache` search XXX в Ubuntu возвращает список пакетов с описанием.

Как установить пакеты из этого списка одной командой `apt-get install` без копирования имени каждого пакета вручную?

Answer (score 1):

Учите консольные утилиты Linux:

```
apt-cache search something | awk '{ print $1 }' | xargs apt-get install
```

Answer (score 0):

```
aptitude install $(aptitude search XXX -F %p)
```

Comment: aptitude search и apt-cache search это не одно и то же.